# can't install visual studio 2015 community on Window 7

Tags: visual-studio, windows-7

I have downloaded visual studio 2015 community on official website and got the exe file named vs_community_CHS.exe. But when I click and tried to install, it just appear a logo called "VisalStudio", then opened a Welcome website and then the logo disappeared and nothing happened. Then I tried to download other installer called vs_community.exe, just happened the same thing as the former exe file. I tried several times and I sitll cannot install Visual Studio community 2015 on Windows 7 SP1. I don't know what to do, and it didn't show me the warning or error, just nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

From the installing Visual Studio page (https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/e2h7fzkw.aspx)

> You need administrator credentials to install Visual Studio. However, you don't >need them to use Visual Studio after you install it.

There is also a troubleshooting guide on that page.